# JNI: Calling GetStaticMethodID blows up

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm writing some code to get a spawned thread to call a static Java method from C++.

The bits that call the method work fine if placed in a native call from Java, but not from a thread with an attached JNIEnv.

I've set a JavaVM* as follows:

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* jvm, void* reserved)
{
    LOGI("Setting Java Virtual Machine");

    ThreadJNIEnvironment::javaVM = jvm;

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

This does get called.

I then spawn another thread and from this thread I do the following:

```
JNIEnv* env;
jint ret = ThreadJNIEnvironment::javaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

LOGI("AttachCurrentThread returned %d", ret);

jclass interfaceClass = env->FindClass("com/ecmsys/mcb/model/McbInterface");
jmethodID testMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(interfaceClass, "Test", "()V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(interfaceClass, testMethod);
```

AttachCurrentThread returns 0.

GetStaticMethod blows up though with the following error:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000002c (code=1).....
```

I just can't see what I've done to upset it...oh wait...you can't access the Java application classes from a spawned thread without doing some set up...

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* jvm, void* reserved)
{
    LOGI("Setting Java Virtual Machine");
    ThreadJNIEnvironment::javaVM = jvm;

    JNIEnv* env;


    jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
    jclass mcbInterface = env->FindClass("com/ecmsys/mcb/model/McbInterface");
    ThreadJNIEnvironment::interfaceClass = env->NewGlobalRef(mcbInterface);

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Then do this:

```
JNIEnv* env;
jint ret = ThreadJNIEnvironment::javaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

LOGI("AttachCurrentThread retured %d", ret);

if(ThreadJNIEnvironment::interfaceClass)
{
    jmethodID testMethod = env-->GetStaticMethodID(static_cast<jclass>ThreadJNIEnvironment::interfaceClass), "Test", "()V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(static_cast<jclass>(ThreadJNIEnvironment::interfaceClass), testMethod);
}


ThreadJNIEnvironment::javaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
```

You live and learn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for exceptions after looking up `interfaceClass` ([`env->ExceptionCheck()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5234)), or simply check that it's non-NULL.  Most likely the class lookup is failing.

Comment: interfaceClass is indeed NULL, thank you. It works fine when called from a native Java call though. I'll work out what I'm doing wrong now!

Comment: It turns out that I needed to create a global reference to my interface class when JNI_OnLoad is called and then use this instead of looking it up from a new thread's JNIEnv instance.

Comment: You might as well cache the method ID (you don't need a reference for that), and you should use a weak global reference for the class.  You need the reference because you're having onto the class reference beyond the scope of a single JNI call (the initial reference you get is a local reference).